# How can I geta list of files in multiple sub-folder with their absolute path in Linux

Tags: linux, absolute-path

I have multiple sub-folder, in every sub-folder have multiple  .txt file.
I want to organize a list with every file.I use this command to get absolute path.

```
find $PWD -type f -name "*.txt"
```

but how do I merge all of them into a text file.

like this

```
/home/2022/Dir/20220103/1.txt
/home/2022/Dir/20220103/2.txt
/home/2022/Dir/20220103/3.txt
/home/2022/Dir/20220103/4.txt
/home/2022/Dir/20220105/1.txt
/home/2022/Dir/20220105/2.txt
/home/2022/Dir/20220105/3.txt
/home/2022/Dir/20220107/11.txt
/home/2022/Dir1/20220211/12.txt
/home/2022/Dir1/20220211/13.txt
/home/2022/Dir1/20220217/1.txt
.
.
.
.
.
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? How is this problem related to programming?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`man find` gives you the answer:

Excerpt:

```
-print True;  print  the full file name on the standard output, followed by a newline. ...
```

Hence (for your case):

```
find $PWD -type f -name "*.txt" -print
```

In order to get the results of any UNIX/Linux command in a file, you just redirect, using the `>` character, like this:

```
find $PWD -type f -name "*.txt" -print >outputfile
```

Comment: Please share more details. How does `-print`  merge all files into another file?

Comment: @NicoHaase: Oops, I had missed that part. I've edited my question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
find "$PWD" -type f -name '*.txt' -exec realpath {} +
```